# ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: ring-theory

consider the ring R=$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$={$a+b\sqrt{-5}: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$} and the element $\alpha=3+\sqrt{-5}$ of R . Then

1. $\alpha$ is prime
2. $\alpha$ is irreducible
3. R is not a unique factorization domain
4. R is not an integral domain

1...($3+\sqrt{-5}$)( $3-\sqrt{-5}$ )=14=2.7$\in$$<\alpha>$ but 2 $\notin<\alpha>$ hence not prime

2...true because every prime is irreducible.

3...true it clear from 1

4...not true because ($a+b\sqrt{-5}$)($c+d\sqrt{-5})$=0 implies either a=b=0 or c=d=0 hence ID

please tell me if any mistake.

Comment: You should check if $7 \in <\alpha>$

Comment: And in integral domain you can say that p is prime iff <p> is prime ideal and every prime is irreducible. You should first show that is integral domain.

Comment: It is not an UFD because $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})= (2)(3)$. Also  $3+\sqrt{-5} \in (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ where $ (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is a non-principal ideal

Comment: Equivalently for showing $\alpha$ is not prime, can we show if $\alpha\nmid2$ and $\alpha\nmid7\implies \alpha\nmid2\cdot 7$ but $\alpha|2\cdot7$. So $\alpha$ is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

you have $3+\sqrt{-5} | 14=2.7$. You have shown $3+\sqrt{-5}$ doesnot divide 2, but you also need to show $3+\sqrt{-5}$ doesnot divide 7, to conclude $\alpha$ is not prime. And how did you conclude (2) is true?

$\alpha$ is not prime, but why is it irreducible? The reason is as follows..

observe first that the units in the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are only 1 and -1. Now let us write $3+\sqrt{-5}= (a+b \sqrt{-5}).(c+d \sqrt{-5})$. Taking complex conjugation on both side( or if you like taking field norm on both sides) we have, $14= (a^{2}+5b^{2})(c^{2}+5d^{2})$. Now observe you can write 14 as 2.7 or 14.1 . Now $a^{2}+5b^{2}=2 $ has no solution in a and b because $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. $a^{2}+5b^{2}=7 $ also has no solution. Hence we have either   $a^{2}+5b^{2}=1 $ or $c^{2}+5d^{2}=1 $, which shows that either $a+b \sqrt{-5}= \pm1 $ or, $c+d \sqrt{-5}=\pm 1$, which imples that one has to be unit, and hence $\alpha$ is irreducible.

You have shown that its an integral domain. It is not an UFD is clear because 14 has two distinct repesentation in terms of irreducibles. Or else as you have concluded that since $\alpha$ is not a prime but an irreducible element, $R$ can never be an UFD, Since in an UFD $\alpha \in R$ is prime iff it is irreducible.

By the way let me also remark that the way I have shown that $\alpha$ is irreducible is a standard trick which is almost applicable to all such similar cases.

Comment: Equivalently for showing $\alpha$ is not prime, can we show if $\alpha\nmid2$ and $\alpha\nmid7\implies \alpha\nmid2\cdot 7$ but $\alpha|2\cdot7$. So $\alpha$ is not prime.